# Not receiving stdout from nodejs spawned process

Tags: node.js, io, child-process, spawn

I'm trying to have *nodejs* interact with *adventure*, an old text based game. The idea is to open adventure as a child process and then play the game by writing to its `stdin` and placing an event listener on `stdout`.

When the game starts, it prints an initial:

> Welcome to Adventure!!  Would you like instructions?

So to illustrate my problem, I have a nodejs+express instance with:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var spawn = childProcess.spawn;
var child = spawn('adventure');

console.log("spawned: " + child.pid);

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log("Child data: " + data);
});
child.on('error', function () {
  console.log("Failed to start child.");
});
child.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('Child process exited with code ' + code);
});
child.stdout.on('end', function () {
  console.log('Finished collecting data chunks.');
});
```

But when I start the server, the text from the game doesn't reach the event listener:

```
spawned: 24250
```

That's all the output I get. The `child.stdout.on` even listener is never called. Why isn't that initial line from the game being picked up?

If I append the following line to the above block of javascript, then the program output appears at once. So `adventure` runs, and I can now force it to trigger the `child.stdout.on` event listener... but this also ends the child process, which defeats the purpose of reading and writing to it.

```
...
child.stdout.on('end', function () {
  console.log('Finished collecting data chunks.');
});
child.stdin.end();
```

Now the output is:

```
spawned: 28778  
Child data:
Welcome to Adventure!!  Would you like instructions?
user closed input stream, quitting...

Finished collecting data chunks.
Child process exited with code 0
```

I'm sure its a trivial oversight on my part, I appreciate any help figuring this out though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After going through the Nodejs documentation a few more times, I convinced myself I was either missing something pretty big, or the `spawn` command wasn't working correctly. So I created a [github issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2926).

And the answer was immediately posted: the child process can't buffer output if you want fast access.

So to achieve what I was originally looking for:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var spawn = childProcess.spawn;
var child = spawn('unbuffer', 'adventure');

console.log("spawned: " + child.pid);

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log("Child data: " + data);
});
child.on('error', function () {
  console.log("Failed to start child.");
});
child.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('Child process exited with code ' + code);
});
child.stdout.on('end', function () {
  console.log('Finished collecting data chunks.');
});
```

With the functional difference being the use of `unbuffer`, a command that disables output buffering.

Comment: In my case I do not have `unbuffer` command on my system, but `{shell: true}` option for `options` parameter of `spawn` produced the output. Also there is `stdbuf` command on Linux to control buffering, but it does not change anything in my case. (I was spawning `java` compiler from `openjdk` package.)

Answer (score 6):

> Why isn't that initial line from the game being picked up?

I had the same problem on a project that called a compiled C++ program from node.js. I realized the problem was in the compiled C++ program: I wasn't flushing the `stdout` stream. Adding `fflush(stdout);` after printing a line solved the issue. Hopefully you still have access to the source of the game!

Comment: It turned out the buffering was taking place on the node.js side, but buffering was the root issue. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` passed is a buffer type, not a string. Therefore, you need a decoder to read that buffer and then do the logging.

Here's how to do that.

```
var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;
var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    var message = decoder.write(data);
    console.log(message.trim());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip on getting usable output from `data`. My problem is that `child.stdout.on()` is never called in the first place, though I know the sub process _is_ writing output. This is the case even if the contents is only `console.log("Something received from child");` and doesn't deal with `data` at all.

Comment: What happens if you open a blank terminal and type `adventure`? Does it print something? I'm curious whether node successfully launched `adventure` or not. Also try using absolute path.

Comment: The quoted text in the question _"Welcome to Adventure..."_ is printed immediately after `adventure` is launched. I have nodejs print the PID so that I can check, and adventure is indeed running. I'll go ahead and add an absolute path to the program name, that strikes me as a good idea.

Comment: Because if `adventure` is not in your path, then launching it as `spawn('adventure')` would fail

Comment: @user528315 - In my case, I'm not able to go inside child.stdout.on(...){ ... } section. What could be the problem. The control goes to 'exit' though and I'm able to get the exit code as 0 (success). I'm just calling a shell script which only echoes "Pass" just one line.