# Node invoking a python script - Weird execution order

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x

I tried a fairly simple script.

```
import time
print("Hello World")
time.sleep(5)
```

This program does exactly what it appears to be doing. It prints `Hello World`, waits for five seconds and then exits.

However, things start getting weird when i invoked this with node.

```
 const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
 const process = spawn ('python3', ['./testIn.py']);

 process.stdout.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data.toString());
 });

 process.on('close', code => {
     console.log(`child process close all stdio with code ${code}`);
 });
```

What happens now is that the program waits for five seconds, then prints `Hello World` and then exits immediately after the print.
It's like the order of the two commands is reversed, first it runs the `sleep()` and the the `print()`.

Does anyone have a clue on why this weird behaviour occurs?

Comment: [Not receiving stdout from nodejs spawned process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32636139)

Comment: Tried  const process = spawn ('unbuffered', 'python3', ['./testIn.py']); but didn't work. Also tried  const process = spawn ('python3 -u', ['./testIn.py']); but didn't work.

Comment: This works as expected on my Windows machine: `const process = spawn ('py', ['-u', 'testIn.py'], {shell: true});`

Comment: Thank you! it worked. It's all about the -u flag after all, but i was declaring it erroneously. If you would like, you can post it as a normal answer, so i can vote up and mark it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is buffering the output so you are not seeing it until the process ends. You can use the `-u` option to tell Python not to do that. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u), the `-u` option will:

> Force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered. This option has no effect on the stdin stream.
> Changed in version 3.7: The text layer of the stdout and stderr streams now is unbuffered.

However, I am running 3.7.2 on Windows 10 and could not get your code to work without the `-u` option.

```
const process = spawn ('py', ['-u', 'testIn.py']);
```