# Python to NodeJS communication not working through spawn

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, debugging

I'm trying to replicate this process to establish communication be nodejs and python through stdin and stdout : https://healeycodes.com/javascript/python/beginners/webdev/2019/04/11/talking-between-languages.html

**Context:**
Sender - which is giving output to stdout

Listener - one who's reading it

Now, when Python is sender and NodeJS is Listener isn't working. NodeJS gives no output.
On further digging my issue is very similar to [Not receiving stdout from nodejs spawned process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598607/not-receiving-stdout-from-nodejs-spawned-process) except I don't need unbuffered output as such. Tried sol from last ques.. didn't work.

**Here are files:**
sensor.py

```js
import random, time
import sys

time.sleep(random.random() * 5)  # wait 0 to 5 seconds
temperature = (random.random() * 20) - 5  # -5 to 15
print(temperature, flush=True, end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

listener.js

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

//spawn()
const child = spawn('python', ['path-to-sensor.py']);
console.log('Here');

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Got the data')
    console.log(data)
  });
  child.on('error', function () {
    console.log("Failed to start child.");
  });
  child.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('Child process exited with code ' + code);
  });
  child.stdout.on('end', function () {
    console.log('Finished collecting data chunks.');
  });
```

**Reason:** Event listener - child.stdout.on('data', callback) is never called

**What I want the output to be:**
Store the stdout from sensor.py in a variable

Can't figure out what else I can do to fix this

Answer (score 0):

In sensor.py you are not using the right syntax in your code:

```
print(temperature, flush=True, end='')
```

The right syntax is:

```
print(object(s), sep=separator, end=end, file=file, flush=flush)
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp)

If you left the code in sensor.py as:

```
print(temperature)
```

And in listener.js as:

```
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Got the data')
    //console.log(data)
    console.log(data.toString('utf8'))
 });
```

It works ok